# React Redux createStore Config

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am developing my project using React and Redux. I am getting below error when I run my project after few days later. Could anyone say why I am getting below error.

[image]

Comment: have you run `npm install` or `yarn` before starting the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I configure redux store:

```
const enhander = compose(applyMiddleware(...featureMiddleware, ...coreMiddleware, logger, thunk));
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, enhander);
```

The only difference is **I provide an initial state which is an empty object**

Greetings.